# array filter and if true map data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping

i have this piece of code which should combine three apicalls together.

API 1: modules (like a container for multiple checkboxes)
data structure is this:

```js
const modules = [
  {
    name: "Modul1",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "Modul2",
    id: 2,
  },
];
```

---

API 2: the elements which should be inside the modules and related to there 
`modules[x].id === elements[x].idModule`

```js
const elements = [
  {
    idModule: 1,
    default: false,
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    idModule: 1,
    default: false,
    id: 2,
  },
  {
    idModule: 1,
    default: false,
    id: 3,
  },
  {
    idModule: 2,
    default: false,
    id: 4,
  },
  {
    idModule: 2,
    default: false,
    id: 5,
  },
  {
    idModule: 2,
    default: false,
    id: 6,
  },
  {
    idModule: 2,
    default: false,
    id: 7,
  },
];
```

---

API 3: the true/false value which should set to the elements related to 
`elements[x].id === items.items[x].id`

```js
const items = {
   "status":true,
   "items":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":3,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":5,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":6,
         "value":true
      },
      {
         "id":7,
         "value":true
      }
   ]
}
```

---

all three APIs should be combined to one single source of truth.
the result should looks like this:

```js
const result = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Module1',
    elements: [
      {
        idModule: 1,
        default: false,
        id: 1,
        value: true
      },
      {
        idModule: 1,
        default: false,
        id: 2,
        value: true
      },
      {
        idModule: 1,
        default: false,
        id: 3,
        value: true
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Module2',
    elements: [
      {
        idModule: 2,
        default: false,
        id: 4,
        value: true
      },
      {
        idModule: 2,
        default: false,
        id: 5,
        value: true
      },
      {
        idModule: 2,
        default: false,
        id: 6,
        value: true
      },
      {
        idModule: 2,
        default: false,
        id: 7,
        value: true
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

my brain is melting by doing this and i am stuck as f. what i tried for now 2 days is this:

```js
const data = data.modules.map(x => {
  x.modules = data.elements.items.filter(
    d => d.idModule === x.id
  );

  x.modul.map(y => {
    // ---------- some where here the shit its the fan, idk -----------
    y.value = data.items.items.filter(f => {
      f.id === y.id; 
    });
    return y;
  });
  return x;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first get the data by mapping the last two API calls, then map the first array with the incoming result:

```js
var modules = [ { name: "Modul1", id: 1, }, { name: "Modul2", id: 2, }];
var elements = [ { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 1, }, { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 2, }, { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 3, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 4, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 5, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 6, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 7, },];
var items = { "status":true, "items":[ { "id":1, "value":true }, { "id":2, "value":true }, { "id":3, "value":true }, { "id":4, "value":true }, { "id":5, "value":true }, { "id":6, "value":true }, { "id":7, "value":true } ]}

var newData = elements.map((val)=>{
  val.value = items.items.find(k=>k.id == val.id).value;
  return val;
});
    
result = modules.map(val=>{
  val.elements = newData.filter(k=>k.idModule == val.id);
  return val;
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: i was sitting two days for this and u rush that in 10mins. i have still much to learn, thank you very much.
now i got it, i tried the wrong way to concat the data. i had to start from bottom down and concat the child data before mapping all into parent obj.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   var modules = [ { name: "Modul1", id: 1, }, { name: "Modul2", id: 2, }];
var elements = [ { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 1, }, { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 2, }, { idModule: 1, default: false, id: 3, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 4, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 5, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 6, }, { idModule: 2, default: false, id: 7, },];
var items = { "status":true, "items":[ { "id":1, "value":true }, { "id":2, "value":true }, { "id":3, "value":true }, { "id":4, "value":true }, { "id":5, "value":true }, { "id":6, "value":true }, { "id":7, "value":true } ]}
 

let arr = modules.map(ele => {
  ele['elements'] = elements.filter(el => el.idModule == ele.id).map(inele => {
    let index = items['items'].map(fi => fi.id).indexOf(inele.id);
    (index != -1) ? inele['value'] = items['items'][index]['value'] : '';
    return inele;
  });
  return ele;
})
console.log(arr);
```